# How to echo a function in php using button?

Tags: php, function, echo

I am making an event calendar.I want to echo a function in php using button.

My actual code:

Calendar.php

```
<?php include_once('functions.php'); ?> 
<?php echo getCalender(); ?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['func']) && !empty($_POST['func'])){
    switch($_POST['func']){
        case 'getCalender':
            getCalender($_POST['year'],$_POST['month']);
            break;
        case 'getEvents':
            getEvents($_POST['date']);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
//Get calendar full HTML
function getCalender($year = '',$month = '')
{
    $dateYear = ($year != '')?$year:date("Y");
    $dateMonth = ($month != '')?$month:date("m");
    $date = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-01';
    $currentMonthFirstDay = date("N",strtotime($date));
    $totalDaysOfMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$dateMonth,$dateYear);
    $totalDaysOfMonthDisplay = ($currentMonthFirstDay == 7)?($totalDaysOfMonth):($totalDaysOfMonth + $currentMonthFirstDay);
    $boxDisplay = ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay <= 35)?35:42;
?>
    <div id="calender_section">
    //
}
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function getCalendar(target_div,year,month){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'functions.php',
            data:'func=getCalender&year='+year+'&month='+month,
            success:function(html){
                $('#'+target_div).html(html);
            }
        });
    }

function getEvents(date){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'functions.php',
            data:'func=getEvents&date='+date,
            success:function(html){
                $('#event_list').html(html);
                $('#event_add').slideUp('slow');
                $('#event_list').slideDown('slow');
            }
        });
    }
```

Now I want to use button to call the getcalendar function. I've tried this:

Calendar.php

```
 <form class="" action="" method="post">
               <input type="button" value="Dhaka" onclick="<?php echo getCalender(); ?>"/>
              </form>
```

Now this is not waitiing for button click. When I refresh the page it is showing the calendat even if i didn't click the button.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for functions.php. You mentioned getCalender instead of getCalendar

---

```
<?php include_once('functions.php'); ?>
<form class="" action="" method="post">
<input type="button" value="Dhaka" onclick="getCalendar()"/>
</form>
```

---

Also, close the script tag in the functions.php file after the getEvents function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
print_f(Object);
```

And then try your code, instead of echo;